# iPhone Developer company registration

Tags: iphone, registration

I applied to Apple iPhone developer program to register my company. Five days later I got an email asking me to fax 3 documents. The first two I know what they are but they are also asking for a "Corporations Charger". Given that this only return 16 useless results in google, it looks like a pretty uncommon weird thing! Anyone got through that process already and can tell me what that is? I live in Canada/Quebec, maybe it does not apply over here?

Comment: I'm willing to bet this is NPR ! ;-)

Comment: We registered but were never asked for anything like this. It was more like certificate of formation, business license, blah blah blah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they mean charter. If I remember correctly, for my (US-based) LLC, I had to send them my CA Secretary Of State filing and my Federal Tax ID.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that the're asking for a charter and not a charger?

Comment: I pasted it from the email ... It looks like a standard email they use for every company registration. I would hope there are no typo in there.

Comment: "g" is just below "t". Looks like a typo.

Comment: I would BET that it is a typo.  You wont believe the amount of atrocious grammar and spelling errors I have seen on official paperwork.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing they meant "corporate charter", but I have no idea how it would get screwed up like that.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this is something like a Purchase Order.